# Dynamically create typescript type for output object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to create the typescript `type` for my object which is `Record<string, string | number, {} | []>` as below -

```
const input = {
  "test": 1,
  "test2": "2",
}

const output = {
  test: {
    "testData": 1,
    "testIsError": false,
  },
  test2: {
    "test2Data": "2",
    "test2IsError": false,
  }
}
```

I want the output keys to be of type object where `${key}Data` is of same type as typeof key in input object.

I am aware the this can be better optimized to below output object which is clean & readable as below -

```
type Value<T> = {
  data: T;
  isError: boolean;
}

type BetterType<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Value<T[K]>;
}

const test = {
  "test": 1,
  "test2": "2",
}

const test2: BetterType<typeof test> = {
  test: {
    data: 1,
    isError: false,
  },
  test2: {
    data: "will infer as string",
    isError: false,
  }
}
```

But, just out of curiosity want to know if my above original problem can be addressed in typescript or not.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WG86Mw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (Please note that `Record<string, string | number, {} | []>` is not valid; could you [edit] to remove that or replace it with something valid?)

Comment: @jcalz yes, this is exactly I was looking for, you can post this as the answer Thanks

Comment: I will do so; could you please [edit] to remove the invalid `Record<string, string | number, {} | []>` or replace it with something valid?

Comment: @jcalz, I can remove the invalid type for the expected values in Record, but to give some more context, I am using this as part of creating the initial slice value in react-redux, so initial value can be of either object, string or number, 
do you suggest it would be better if i create a type of that like `type Value string | number | Record<any, any>` and then use this in my main type ?

Comment: I can't really answer without a [mre] of the code and it's probably out of scope here.  I'd start with `string | number | object` and change it only if the use cases require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be inclined to define your type as:

```
type InToOut<T extends object> = { [K in keyof T]:
  { [P in "Data" | "IsError" as `${Exclude<K, symbol>}${P}`]:
    P extends "Data" ? T[K] : boolean
  }
};
```

which results in the transformation I think you're looking for:

```
const input = {
  "test": 1,
  "test2": "2",
}
    
type Out = InToOut<typeof input>;
/* type Out = {
    test: {
        testData: number;
        testIsError: boolean;
    };
    test2: {
        test2Data: string;
        test2IsError: boolean;
    };
} */
```

---

How it works:

```
type InToOut<T extends object> = { [K in keyof T]:
  { [P in "Data" | "IsError" as `${Exclude<K, symbol>}${P}`]:
    P extends "Data" ? T[K] : boolean
  }
};
```

That's a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) were each property with key `K` in the input type `T` is transformed to an output property type with the same key. That output property type is

```
{ [P in "Data" | "IsError" as `${Exclude<K, symbol>}${P}`]:
  P extends "Data" ? T[K] : boolean
}
```

which is another mapped type; this one iterates over the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"Data"` and `"IsError"`, and for each one of them outputs a property with a transformed *key*, using [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).  That transformed key is `` `${Exclude<K, symbol>}${P}` ``, which is a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) representing the concatenation of the key `K` from the original object, with `P` from either `"Data"` or `"IsError"`.  Conceptually that template literal type would be `` `${K}${P}` ``, but since `K` might be a `symbol` and since `symbol`s are not properly serializable via template literals, we need to exclude `symbol`s from consideration... hence the use of [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) and `Exclude<K, symbol>`.

So the key is either `K`-with-`"Data"`-appended or `K`-with-`"IsError"` appended.  The value is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) `P extends "Data" ? T[K] : boolean`, so if `"Data"` has been appended then the property is `T[K]`, the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) corresponding to the property at key `K` from the original `T` object type; and if `"IsError"` is appended then the property is `boolean`.

---

By the way you don't have to use key remapping and conditional types to get an equivalent type, but I like the way the output type looks.  An equivalent solution is:

```
type InToOut<T extends object> =
  { [K in Exclude<keyof T, symbol>]:
    { [P in `${K}Data`]: T[K] } &
    { [P in `${K}IsError`]: boolean }
  };

type Out = InToOut<typeof input>;
/* type Out = {
      test: {
        testData: number;
      } & {
        testIsError: boolean;
      };
      test2: {
        test2Data: string;
      } & {
        test2IsError: boolean;
      };
} */
```

which uses an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) to join the `K`+`"Data"` and the `K`+`"IsError"` properties into one object.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgEoRggwDCA9sACYCWALnoUUvE1J1bAYAV04BeLjx4AidtHYyAXEgCMAGm7S5CgEzKkM-ZukBffFqTsAnjGQBJYABUGAeTEAeJ0ggAPeSxQSAwARgBWEPDsAHxIkrhIANoA0khCSADWENYMAGZITgC6SpZECYkACmnAhgAiIOwgMkgAPob2UACiAE7dDN3NIEEABgAkuJ2+8BgizBAeyepIUNZgIQwY0abjFabDxaU8VX4BzEEy9Y3NAPwFKYVIKusbECDAh+ZmANwW0jZ2SHcEiQjhcQI8-wgeWqohiP2kAHoAFRWWzIIFxKTSHjyAQqAjYwlWBSXEAqYAiNYQbrwol-BQdHp9bpPBgvN60wmmTnY3HsXT4w6Evm6UkqATdIQAcx5dJFjN6-VZ7OAsp43MspiQSIRvx4fGAAmCYlhKgx8UOfMFdJ0AlJBg0QsMfIVzIMuUwUAgJmxph99IEAqxhNt-PtKiMMn92NDuld-Xdnu9H013E+xHA0DgiCQVD43WYjnk3S9UWDvH4gmEYkxBJjfId0aIsYMkej5kskJBzjcnm8JwggWC4UiMTih3KqXSk2ms3mWRy+ScSxWaw20QOdPKVXSY1wyVMpP2Kic9yQWoAZE7t9UkHuD-HusekM8MK8aunvnqiF3zd2wZ4kLQkIsLRDyyKogCf51nKCjWnSOIkg0ZLEJSITUmqZhIBe5awQIj7Km+HJOkQGoIcSgbweRIpiss7CSsAMokee2G4US8pdIqLIvmyRGqsxZHqtquqWAaRoMCaYhmjWFrCnBbHNny4ZqE2sgupxboqB6GBeqpfqWnoVH1noyltk6saPomOnJlyqakRYphAA)